# What documentation tag should I use for proxy method

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

let's say I have a code like this:

```
class A
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Some important text here
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <param name="b"></param>
    /// <param name="c"></param>
    public void Method1(int a, int b, int c)
    {
    }
}
class B
{
    private A a = new A();

    // I'd like to show A.Method1 documentation here
    public void Method1(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        this.a.Method1(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Is there any standard documentation tag (eg. standard enough to show proper documentation in Visual Studio) that would accomplish that?

I want to do something like this:

```
/// <SomeMagicTag ref="A.Method1" />
public void Method1(int a, int b, int c)
```

and have the visual studio show me documentation for `A.Method1` when I use `B.Method1`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Those are 2 different classes and over the course of development, could lead to entirely different behavior/syntax/results. If they are not coupled in anyway, then you should not couple their documentation.

Comment: @Mrchief: If they differ then I'll rewrite the documentation, right now it's just as shown in the example.

Comment: So if keeping them in sync is not a goal, why not just copy/paste? Or do you have more such cases rather than just one offhand method?

Comment: @Mrchief: I've edited the question to better explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I got that, but I was trying to understand your reasoning behind creating proxy classes. I mean why not go with inheritance? Then you'll have few more avenues open to you. With this arrangement however, and coupled with the fact that you want Intellisense to show it (and not some generated documentation), your best bet is to have something like this: `/// <summary>/// Proxies <see cref="A.Method1(int, int, int)"/>/// </summary>`

Comment: @Mrchief: The reasoning is that I have a class which contains another class and I want to expose just selected methods of the inner class and not whole class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sort of figured it out. Sadly this method doesn't work for visual studio intellisense (at least not in VS2013), but it does work for sandcastle help file builder.

Here is edited example from my question to show how to do it:

```
/// <inheritdoc cref="A.Method1" />
public void Method1(int a, int b, int c)
```

It can be further customized by using the `select` attribute which can contain xpath query for inheriting only selected tags from the referenced comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cref attribute in order to reference the method of Class A.

> The cref attribute in an XML documentation tag means "code reference." It specifies that the inner text of the tag is a code element, such as a type, method, or property

Take a look at Microsoft documentation:
[cRef Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc837134.aspx)

Comment: I guess I could do that, but it doesn't seem to work exactly how I would like it. I'd like to show exactly the same documentation for the proxy method as for the original method, this only inserts some sort of a link.